# regex change position of string in a word

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have multiple lines with `log_filename other text` which I would like to replace with `filename.log other text`. How would I go about doing this?

```
weather_aspire_update/weather/ > /tmp/log_weathrdata 2>&1
mail_data/diamond_mail_read.py >/tmp/log_diamonddata 2>&1
```

I have edited to include examples.

Edit: It's a crontab entry which I'm trying to edit with vim. I'm using vim's regex substitution feature.

Comment: A regular expression alone cannot change text at all, only match it. There are many tools which facilitate regex search and replace, but the feature set will depend on the platform. Please [edit] your question to provide details in accordance with the requirements in the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the info you described is in a file named `myfile`, you can use the following command

```
sed 's/log_\([^ ]*\)/\1.log/' yourfile > newfile
mv newfile yourfile
```

or

```
sed -i 's/log_\([^ ]*\)/\1.log/' yourfile
```

which is not POSIX compliant.

Besides, I'm assuming `log_filename` does not contain any space, so that I can match it with `[^ ]*` (*as many successive non-spaces as possible*). If it does contain one or more space, then you should clarify a rule to distinguish its space-separated parts from `other` and `text` (which I expect can be one or more words in general, too).

Comment: I tried the first version and it worked. Thank you.